# Parse Server Android SDK query retrieves list of empty values

Tags: android, parse-server

I am using self hosted Parse server (Using Ubuntu Server). For my Android app, have following dependencies,

```
****compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'****
```

I am able to save the data in cloud. The problem is when I try to retrieve the data its giving list of data (eg. list of 10 objects). But its fields didn't have the actual value that I have saved. Its shows the default value of the field type (eg. String = null, int = 0, double = 0.0)

Example Saving Data

```
Rich {
   String name = "UserName",
   int age = 22,
   double weight = 58
}
```

Example Retrieved Data

```
[
   Rich {
      name = null,
      age = 0,
      weight = 0.0
   },
   ...
   ...
]
```

I am querying as follows

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Rich");
List list = query.find();
```

If you guys know about the issue, please tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to add one thing. Already I am using Xamarin.Forms Parse nuget library. Its works good with all kind of parse operatioin. The issue only exist with android sdk for parse server

Comment: Have you verified the data on the server?  You can see it in some kind of viewer, or retrieve it with a different platform?

Comment: Yes, I can see the data in server. Using Chrome ARC able to retrieve the data. And able to retrieve in Xamarin.Android application.

Comment: If you call `getObjectId` on the retrieved objects, are they correct?  If so, you could fetch each one as a workaround.  I'm not sure why the data wouldn't come back though.  If you don't get object ids, then I don't know what to think.

Comment: Sorry guys. Its working as expected. Able to retrieve the data by passing the name of the key. I have missed that part. (eg. String name = obj.getString("name")). thank you nasch. :)